# Iphone & Similar phone's Development

Tags: mobile

I am working as a junior developer at the moment , I have good and growing skills in PHP , MySql , Javascript as well as XHTML & CSS.

I got asked at work today "How can we use our web app on a Iphone or similar product ?"

SO what I need to know is:

Do I build mobile site for our exciting site and make it fit the screens of a mobile device .

or

Do I build a Application ?

If I was to build an application what languages are used to typically build an App whats similar to a website in terms in MySql database etc

Answer (score 1):

Building a mobile site is probably the quickest way to get on all the phones, and will be easier to maintain that several native app codebases. That's the route I took for some internal tools that need to be accessible by iPhone and Blackberry users.

Your Javascript, HTML, and CSS skills will serve you well there. If you go for native apps you'll need to learn other languages like Objective-C. (Of course, picking up new languages is part of the fun.)

Depending on the phone, native apps can give you some distinct advantages. It's just a matter of whether or not you need those features.

Comment: Yeah , I think I will go down the mobile site route for the time as I want to develop my Web Languages to a higher level first.